# Aggregation using WITH in Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For the following 2 nodes: (a)-[rel]-(b) where (a) has a unique property say Id and (b) has a timestamp property.

For a given number of Id values, I want to retrieve the (b) node with latest timestamp connected to (a) node. After that I intend to set some properties in the latest (b).

The query I wrote is something like:

```
Match p=(a)-[rel]-(b) where a.Id IN ["id1","id2","id3","id4","id5"] WITH MAX(b.timestamp) as MAXT MATCH (b) where b.timestamp=MAXT SET b.prop1=value1, b.prop2=value2
```

But this is returning me only one (b) node out of the all (b) nodes connected to all the (a) nodes.

I tried to group using ORDER BY after WITH but it isn't working as well:

```
Match p=(a)-[rel]-(b) where a.Id IN ["id1","id2","id3","id4","id5"] WITH MAX(b.timestamp) as MAXT ORDER BY a  MATCH (b) where b.timestamp=MAXT SET b.prop1=value1, b.prop2=value2
```

I want to achieve this in a single query as the number of Id's is huge. So, It will be better to do it in a single query rather than multiple queries.

Help will be appreciated.

Regards,

Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to find the maximum per `a` node you cannot do global sorting by `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. Instead you need to pass through using `WITH` the maximum timestamp per `a`, and the collection of `b` nodes. The latter is filtered for maximum in the next step (here in the `RETURN`). `head` function is used to just return the first element of the filtered collection (aka the node with max timestamp):

```
MATCH (a)-[rel]-(b) 
WHERE a.Id in [...]
WITH a, max(b.timestamp) as bmax, collect(b) as bs
RETURN a, head(filter(x in bs where x.timestamp=bmax))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using `ORDER BY` on all the `b`s' timestamps, like this:

```
MATCH (a)-[rel]-(b) 
WHERE a.Id in [...]
WITH a, b 
ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC
WITH a, head(collect(b)) as b
SET b.prop1=value1, b.prop2=value2
```

Comment: This approach will have significant memory overhead on the server side since a global list holding all timestamps needs to be populated and sorted.